# How to show the Michael line has point-countable base?

Tags: general-topology

Michael line can be seen [here](http://six.rdaili.com/sohu.com.php?u=ctzzH7iF9TPPeepscdn%2byb0939GDhuXkGUEj8JAsfntVbwUH0%2bnAZ32UQlgwchf5rB5TctYjcdWEn8R7DPTcGqvHf4AOWiCaWtInAQ==&b=3&f=norefer). It said this space has point-countable base by using a countable base for the usual topology on $R$ with all singletons from $R\setminus Q$. I try to prove it is true. It is easy for any $x\in R\setminus Q$, because it exists the open set ${x}$ which intersects the given base at most countable. However, if $x\in Q$, can we get an open set such that intersects the base at most countable? I'm afraid maybe it will include uncountable points from $R\setminus Q$. Somebody help me!

Comment: Note that _point countable_ means that each point belongs to only finitely many members of the family.  (You seem to be using _locally countable_ in your question.)

Comment: @Arthur: ‘... to only countably many ...’.

Comment: @Brian: Doesn't finite = countable?  (oops...)

Comment: @Arthur: Depends on how good the beer is. *hic*

Comment: O, My heaven...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$\mathscr{B}=\{(p,q):p,q\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p<q\}\cup\big\{\{x\}:x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\big\}\;.$$ Then $\mathscr{B}$ is a point countable base for the Michael line because $\mathscr{B}_0=\{(p,q):p,q\in\Bbb Q\text{ and }p<q\}$ is countable: any $x\in\Bbb R$ belongs to at most countably many members of $\mathscr{B}_0$ and to at most one of the singletons in $\mathscr{B}$.

Note that any base for the Michael line must include $\big\{\{x\}:x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\big\}$, so no base can be *locally* countable: any open set containing a point $q\in\Bbb Q$ will necessarily contain uncountably many of the irrational singletons.